# JPA - One to Many association without a join column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to write a JPA entity class that has a one to many relationship. I would like to avoid defining the relationship in the parent class to avoid the data to be loaded every time a reference is made for the object even when there is no need for the associated data. I have read that even with Lazy loading, the data can be loaded so i need to avoid that.

In the following example,

```
Customer table
------------------------
customerid, customerName
1           John
2           Bob
```

Order Table - customerId is a foreign key to Customer

```
orderId, customerId, orderDate
1        1           12MAY2012 
1        1           13MAY2012
1        2           16MAY2012
```

JPA Entities

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    // all Customer-related fields WITHOUT @OneToMany relationship with Order
}

@Entity
public class Order {

    String orderDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer owner;
}
```

How would i retrieve data from the customer table based on a condition on the order table? For example, how can i say "Get me all customers who have made an order where the orderDate is between two dates?

Comment: If you use lazy loading, the data _shouldn't_ be loaded until it's referenced. It seems that you're trying to solve the wrong problem. How exactly do you expect to create an association between tables without using a join column/table?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation about HQL and associations? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins

Comment: @matt-ball If you define a relationship as lazy the implementation is still permitted to load the relationship eagerly. [The JPA 2 spec says so](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html) .

Comment: @siebz0r: No serious implementation would do that, especially for XxxToMany associations. Hibernate certainly doesn't.

Comment: @JB Nizet If you want to trust the implementation, that's fine. I for one prefer to follow the specification.

Comment: So you would avoid using toMany associations, just because the spec says an implementation is allowed to ignore the lazy fetching attribute, although the implementation you chose, as all the other implementations in existence, honor it? Do you also avoid foreign key constraints in Oracle because MySQL with MyISAM doesn't support them?

Comment: @JBNizet No. I'm just saying you need to count on the fact that an implementation may decide to do an eager fetch, even if it doesn't make sense. If you're sure it's safe to use lazy (like with Hibernate) it's not a problem, however if you're not sure, I'd say stick to the spec just to be sure. I think there is nothing wrong with following the specs, if there is, please tell me as I'm still learning.

Comment: I am using Hibernate but i was worried as it was unclear because it looked like even declaring a LAZY relationship the implementation could load the data. I just dont want to take risks especially when the data that could be loaded could be > 100k rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using hbm.xml there are query only properties to achieve what you want

http://ayende.com/blog/4054/nhibernate-query-only-properties